# Is there a white or green card that turns an artifact into a creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I'm looking for white or green cards that turn an artifact into a creature indefinitely while retaining their abilities (similar to [March of the Machines](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarch%20of%20the%20Machines%5d)).  Is there a card like that?

Comment: "Identical" would be eay to answer, but what exactly do you mean by "similar"?

Comment: Well i mean anything identical,  similar,  or same as i really only need to transform Paradox engine in my combo deck so i can protect it with other affects something more "permanent" preferably

Comment: @KCkingcollin It sounds like you are looking for white or green cards that turn an artifact into a creature indefinitely while retaining their abilities. If I understood correctly, would you mind updating the question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The closest equivalent to [March of the Machines](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarch%20of%20the%20Machines%5d) in white or green is [Titania's Song](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTitania%27s%5d%2b%5bSong%5d).**

It has equal converted mana cost. The most signficant difference to March is that the animated artifacts lose their abilities.

I found that card through [this Gatherer search](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[each]+[artifact]+[creature]+[power]+[toughness]+[is]), so you might find something else to your liking, or you could refine the search to include other cards. For example, [Karn, Silver Golem](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKarn%2c%20Silver%20Golem%5d) is an artifact creature that also animates artifacts, except one by one and only until end of turn.

Comment: [Opalescence](https://magiccards.info/query?q=opalescence&v=card&s=cname) also has a similar effect, but for enchantments instead of artifacts. The CMC is also the same, although it takes 2 colored mana instead of just one.

Comment: @J. Sallé i honestly didn't think that existed so I didn't ask but that really helps thanks

Comment: @KCkingcollin If you want to go down the MtG rules rabbit hole, complete with timestamps and Layers, look up Humility on the Gatherer and read its rulings on how it interacts with Opalescence.